# How to fix bootstrap body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a sample website using bootstrap but when i try to re size window or open the site on a mobile right side of the site stick to the border of screen you can view site on [chaddi.tk](http://www.chaddi.tk)

HTML here

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TITLE!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input class="burger-check" id="burger-check" type="checkbox"><label for="burger-check" class="burger"></label>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>
    <nav id="navigation1" class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span></li> 
        <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact Me</a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
    </ul>

    </nav>

    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Example page header</h1>  <!--Practical name and number  -->
    </div>
        <div class="table-responsive" id="main_table">
            <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center">No.</th>
                <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Download</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center">1</td>
                <td class="text-center">xxxx</td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="download/1.jpg" download="TT.png"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">DOWNLOAD</button></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center">2</td>
                <td class="text-center">yyyy</td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="download/2.jpg" download="TT.png"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">DOWNLOAD</button></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center">3</td>
                <td class="text-center">zzzzz</td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="download/3.jpg" download="TT.png"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">DOWNLOAD</button></a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    <!-- modal starts here -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="send.php">  
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1>Contact Me </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-msg" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <textarea name="msg" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/shubhamdeshmukh193" target="_blank"><img class="pull-left" src="images/fb.png" alt="Contact on Facebook" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>
                      <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- till here -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css here

```
    .burger {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 4px solid currentColor;
  width: 28px;
  transition: border-bottom 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 1s ease-in-out;
}
.burger::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.burger:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 4px solid currentColor;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.burger:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 4px solid currentColor;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.burger-check {
  display: none;
}

.burger-check:checked ~ .burger {
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.burger-check:checked ~ .burger:before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-405deg) translateY(1px) translateX(-3px);
      transform: rotate(-405deg) translateY(1px) translateX(-3px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg) translateY(1px) translateX(-3px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.burger-check:checked ~ .burger:after {
  -ms-transform: rotate(405deg) translateY(-4px) translateX(-5px);
      transform: rotate(405deg) translateY(-4px) translateX(-5px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg) translateY(-4px) translateX(-5px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.burger-check:checked ~ .navigation {
  max-height: 500px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

body {
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  display:center;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

small {
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h1{
    font: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.table {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right:50px;
}
#main_table{
    float: center;
    width: 900px auto;
    margin: 30px; 
    border-top: 2px solid #808080;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;
    border-left: 2px solid #808080;
    border-right: 2px solid #808080;
}
.modal {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.modal:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
html, body {width: 100%;}
```

i am new to this stuff so if u find any error plz tell me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enclose your header and table inside a `.container` class and remove margin from `#main_table` id from your mystyle.css

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `.container` element.

```
<body>
     <!-- sometimes we put the nav here -->
     <div class="container">
         <!-- your markup -->
     </div>
</body>
```

Take a look [at this demo bootply](http://www.bootply.com/KbaiQyPSrA)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the table in a div with the class of jumbotron.
Then you can style the jumbotron using css.
The jumbotron is responsive and i believe it stays at 70% of the viewport.
Your code looks like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron"><!--Begin of the jumbotron div-->
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Example page header</h1>  <!--Practical name and number  -->
    </div>
        <div class="table-responsive" id="main_table">
            <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center">No.</th>
                <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Download</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center">1</td>
                <td class="text-center">xxxx</td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="download/1.jpg" download="TT.png"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">DOWNLOAD</button></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center">2</td>
                <td class="text-center">yyyy</td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="download/2.jpg" download="TT.png"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">DOWNLOAD</button></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center">3</td>
                <td class="text-center">zzzzz</td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="download/3.jpg" download="TT.png"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">DOWNLOAD</button></a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
</div><!--End of the jumbotron div-->
```